# How to prevent Console application from moved?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm facing big issue with console app using c# core 2.0.

I still didn't find any right answer to lock console window position.
It is movable by the user.

Main problem is if user move console window to any corner of current resolution then console changing its original size even if I set fixed size in program my certain Text are showing bad after changing cmd size.

Windows snap feature is changing its original size.

- I just want to disable windows snap feature without restarting

or

- Lock the console app from being moved by the user

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370169/c-sharp-how-to-prevent-a-console-app-being-moved).

Comment: Previous question was not clearly mentioned. Thats why in this i clearly mentioned all details.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i found real solution for this.**

I was searching a real solution for my application.
There are many tricks but using reg we need to restart computer.

You can disable it from powershell. You need to call this file from your code.

Here is link.

Check download file at bottom called "DisableAeroSnap.ps1"

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-disable-aerosnap-automatically-window-arranging-and-resizing-while-dragging/#more-951

Cheers !!!